# Function to compare lists: no __cmp__

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I have a list of objects that I want to sort. Each object has an id which is a list of strings.

So I defined:

```
class MyObject(object):
    ...
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return self.id.__cmp__(other.id)
```

to which python (2.7) said

```
object 'list' has no attribute '__cmp__'
```

So I defined the six 'rich comparison' ... but is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only thing you need ordering for is *sorting* your objects, it might be better to use `key` argument when calling `sorted`.

```
sorted(list_of_objects, key=lambda x: x.id)
```

---

Rich comparisons are preferred to `__cmp__` and that's why `list`s don't have `__cmp__`.

In your particular case you can use `cmp` function instead which will perform all the comparisons for you:

```
return cmp(self.id, other.id)
```

By the way it is not neccessary to define all six operators.

> If the object on the left side of the operator does not define an
>       appropriate rich comparison operator (either at the C level or
>       with one of the special methods), then the comparison is reversed,
>       and the right hand operator is called with the opposite operator,
>       and the two objects are swapped. This assumes that a < b and b > a
>       are equivalent, as are `a <= b` and `b >= a`, and that `==` and `!=` are
>       commutative (e.g. `a == b` if and only if `b == a`).